# How to override `TemplateView.as_view()` and use ConfirmEmailView for email verification?

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I get this error:

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /rest-auth/registration/account-confirm-email...

TemplateResponseMixin requires either a definition of 'template_name' or an implementation of 'get_template_names()'
```

I cannot understand the documentation: https://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html

It is not clear how to implement step-by-step. I even tried following the link below but I still cannot fix the problem:

https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/issues/15

Can someone provide step-by-step instructions on how to override own view and make sure the when a user gets the email confirmation and clicks on the link, the user can successfully confirm email without that error?

Here is the `urls.py` in my project folder:

```
from django.urls import include, path
from django.contrib import admin
from myapp import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('myapp.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    path('rest-auth/', include('rest_auth.urls')),
    path('rest-auth/registration/', include('rest_auth.registration.urls')),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The original `account-confirm-email` url needs to be overwritten.

You should create your own `ConfirmEmailView`, which can be found [here](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/account/views.py#L264) as a sample. Copy that `ConfirmEmailView` to the `views.py` in your app. Of course, you need to make some modifications to make the code run properly in your app. Such as implementing your key-confirmation process, changing the `template_name` in the class and replacing the variables from `app_settings` in his code. If you also use the `django-rest-auth` for sending the email, you won’t need to make lots of modifications.

Then, add `url(r'^rest-auth/registration/account-confirm-email/(?P<key>[-:\w]+)/$', views.ConfirmEmailView.as_view(), name='account_confirm_email')` to `urlpatterns` in your  `url.py`

Now, it should work fine.

Comment: Thank you, but why do I have to make more modifications like the key-confirmation? Everything works well. It is just that when the user clicks on the link, they get that error. I just need to make sure that the correct template is shown. How can I point it to the right template? I don't know why it can't find that template that gives message that email is confirmed.

Comment: In most case, the documents should mention of that. But in this case, it was put into the FAQ. So, it is not discovered until you run the tests. It is the unit test that can help you find the requirement for modification like that.